# How are Google Sheets array formulas different from Excel (count until sum reached)

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas

I'd like to know which column is the last column where the sum of the values of the row is smaller or equal to a given value. (Count the columns until a sum is reached.)

In Microsoft Excel the following array formula works just fine:

```
{=MATCH(7;SUBTOTAL(9;OFFSET(C1;;;1;COLUMN(C1:G1)-COLUMN(C1)+1));1)}
```

But Google Sheets always returns `1` as an answer:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(7;SUBTOTAL(9;OFFSET(C1;;;1;COLUMN(C1:G1)-COLUMN(C1)+1));1))
```

Is there some difference between Excel and Google Sheets array formulas that I'm missing?

If there is a difference is it documented somewhere?

Is there another way to implement this in Google Sheets (preferably without custom functions)?

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ch6SmrwSEkKC0YcS31giB4tSsQ-DBHFm5nIFQ0eZLOo/) to sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there some difference between Excel and Google Spreadsheet array
>   formulas that I'm missing?

The difference is how specific functions are supported in array formulae. In this case, you're out of luck on two counts: OFFSET can't be iterated over an array (ie it can't produce an "array of arrays" as it can in Excel), and the second argument of SUBTOTAL can't be iterated either; in Sheets, it must be an explicit range.

> If there is a difference is it documented somewhere?

No, not that I know of.

> Is there another way to implement this in Google Spreadsheet
>   (preferably without custom functions)?

`=ArrayFormula(MATCH(7;SUMIF(COLUMN(C1:G1);"<="&COLUMN(C1:G1);C1:G1)))`